# Search bar to search content in a single page website

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single-page website that searches the product and displays it in a product div. I have used javascript onclick to redirect the page to product div. It is working in desktop view but there is a problem in Mobile view. When I search in the Mobile view and click the search button then the page is not redirecting to the div the first time. It closes the virtual keyboard on the first click and redirects after the second click when the keyboard is hidden.

I want to redirect directly when the button is pressed. I have tried the blur() function but it is not working. I have checked to redirect to the other page and it is working but I want to redirect to the div on the same page because I have a single-page website

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="index.php/#cat_1">

  <div  class="d-inline-flex ">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search">

        <button   style="padding:0px; margin-left:5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-info"   id="search_btn">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style="color: white; font-size:20px;"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

```
$( "#search_btn" ).click(function() {$( "#search_btn" ).click();location.href='#cat_1'});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know what your code is like, hence we cannot tell you where your problem is